# Modal won't open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on a site that has come from someone else. He/she made a real mess out of it and apparently right now I am incapable of making a simple modal appear.. On the specific page which I am working on, there is a button to send messages to users which first gives a modal to enter extra variables (message,subject etc). I would now want the same but I am gonna build another purpose for this but to get there I first need a modal to appear...

The send-message button and modal are working but the send-advice is not. this is the code from the source because the system is very complex with views within views etc.. But if it's really necassary I can always add it.

```
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->hasRole(['coach', 'manager']))
<div class="popup-block" id="modal-send-message">
    <div class="popup-in-block">
        <div class="popup-content">
            <div class="request-form-block clearfix">
                <div class="form-block">

                    <a href="#" class="close-btn"></a>

                    <h2>
                        <span class="icon"><i class="feedback-your-coach-icon"></i></span>
                        <span class="title">Herinnering sturen</span>
                    </h2>


                    <div class="text-left">
                        <div class="alert alert-success hide"><span>Herinnering(en)</span> verzonden! Dit venster sluit in 2 seconden.</div>

                        {!! Form::open(['id' => 'form-send-message']) !!}
                            {!! Form::hidden('record_ids') !!}
                            {!! Form::hidden('client_emails') !!}

                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('mail_template', 'Sjabloon') !!}
                                {!! Form::select('mail_template', ['- Kies een sjabloon -'], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'data-query-subject-field' => '#modal_contact_subject', 'data-query-message-field' => '#modal_contact_message', 'data-load-mail-templates' => '1']) !!}
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('to', 'Aan') !!}
                                <p class="static-form-control to-clients"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('subject', 'Onderwerp') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('subject', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'id' => 'modal_contact_subject']) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('message', 'Berichttekst') !!}
                                {!! Form::textarea('message', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'id' => 'modal_contact_message', 'rows' => 5]) !!}
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" id="mark_result_reminder_sent_option" style="display: none">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>{!! Form::checkbox('mark_result_reminder_sent', 1) !!} Markeer dit bericht als een herinnering, voor filtering in het overzicht</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-bottom">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleer</button>
                                <button type="submit" form="form-send-message" class="btn btn-primary">Versturen</button>
                            </div>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif


@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->hasRole(['coach', 'manager']))
<div class="popup-block" id="modal-send-advice">
    <div class="popup-in-block">
        <div class="popup-content">
            <div class="request-form-block clearfix">
                <div class="form-block">

                    <a href="#" class="close-btn"></a>

                    <h2>
                        <span class="icon"><i class="feedback-your-coach-icon"></i></span>
                        <span class="title">Advies sturen</span>
                    </h2>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Code for the modal

```
<div class="top-fillter-block">
    <div class="pull-right communication-btns">
        <span class="close-ico visible-xs">sluit</span>

        <button data-toggle="send-message" data-target="#modal-send-message" data-record-type="user" class="btn1">
        <span class="sms-icon"><strong>Bericht sturen</strong></span>
        </button>
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-send-advice" data-record-type="user" class="btn1">
            <span class="sms-icon"><strong>Advies geven</strong></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code for the button

So to be clear: the modal-send-message is opened when enabling the button send-message, but when enabling the send-advice button it's shown for a few seconds while the page refreshes and then disappears

Comment: Is there any error message in the browser's console?

Comment: No, i have checked @SaidbakR

Comment: Well, you are, mostly, talking about jqueryui modal and javascript. So where is your Javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed some classes name and the working code below

`popup-in-block` with `modal-content` 
`popup-content` with  `modal-header` and
`popup-block` with `modal fade`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
 <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-send-message" data-record-type="user" class="btn1">show
        </button>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-send-message">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="form-block">

                    <a href="#" class="close-btn"></a>

                    <h2>
                        <span class="icon"><i class="feedback-your-coach-icon"></i></span>
                        <span class="title">Herinnering sturen</span>
                    </h2>


                    <div class="text-left">
                        <div class="alert alert-success hide">

                            <div class="form-group">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('to', 'Aan') !!}
                                <p class="static-form-control to-clients"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" id="mark_result_reminder_sent_option" style="display: none">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-bottom">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleer</button>
                                <button type="submit" form="form-send-message" class="btn btn-primary">Versturen</button>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-target="#modal-send-message"` to the button `"send-message"` and `data-target="#modal-send-advice"` to the button `"send-advice"`

Comment: Do you mean `data-target`?

Comment: If it's so obvious add it ;-). But this still isn't working.

Comment: Updated my question!

Comment: Now that I have changed the data-toggle to modal, the modal is shown for a few seconds while the page reloads!